# How to export a special file from ZIP archive?

Tags: bash, shell, zip

I have a ZIP archive with many files, is there any way to export or extract a special file from the ZIP archive without unzip the whole archive?

For example, test.zip has a.txt & b.txt, how to extract a.txt only?

```
test.zip/
        a.txt
        b.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is:

```
unzip test.zip a.txt
```

The argument after the filename is the file to be extracted. In case read:

```
man unzip
```

Answer (score 0):

unzip has an option -x with which you can say which files you don't need

manpage of unzip tells this

> unzip data1 -x joe   => extract all files except joe from zipfile data1.zip

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I want to extract the special file from an archive, not to except it.