# How to extract only one kind of file from the archive?

Tags: shell, terminal, unzip, unrar

Given a .zip or .rar archive containing 10 files, each with different extensions.

Given I only want the .jpg file in it.

**How to extract the *.jpg in it without having to extract the 9 other files ?**

Comment: seems the answer was just nearby.

Comment: Partially did actually : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356849/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
unzip test.zip '*.jpg'
```

The argument after the filename is the file to be extracted. See [`man unzip` Arguments section](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/unzip1.html):

> ```
>    [file(s)]
>           An  optional  list of archive members to be processed, separated
>           by spaces.  (VMS versions  compiled  with  VMSCLI  defined  must
>           delimit  files  with  commas instead.  See -v in OPTIONS below.)
>           Regular expressions (wildcards) may be used  to  match  multiple
>           members;  see  above.   Again, **be sure to quote expressions that
>           would otherwise be expanded** or modified by the operating system.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
tar -xf test.tar --wildcards --no-anchored '*.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
while read -r f; do
    tar -xf "$zipFile" "$f"
done < <(tar tf "$zipFile" | grep '\.jpg')
```